# Average of an array and associate with name

Tags: java, arrays, average

Does anyone know how to display the average race time for participants in this simple program?
It would also be great to display the associated runners name with the time. 
I think that I have the arrays structure properly and have taken in the user input.
Thanks for any assistance you can provide. Here's my code...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class RunningProg
 {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    int num;

    Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to Running Statistical Analysis Application");
    System.out.println("******************************************************************* \n");

    System.out.println("Please input number of participants (2 to 10)");

    num=input.nextInt();

    // If the user enters an invalid number... display error message... 
    while(num<2|| num >10)
    {
    System.out.println("Error invalid input! Try again! \nPlease input a valid number of participants (2-10)...");

        num=input.nextInt();
    }

    // declare arrays
    double resultArray [] = new double [num]; // create result array with new operator
    String nameArray [] = new String [num];// create name array with new operator
    // Using the num int will ensure that the array holds the number of elements inputed by user

      // loop to take in user input for both arrays (name and result)
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nameArray.length ; i++)
        {
            System.out.println ("Please enter a race participant Name for runner " + (i+1) );
            nameArray[i] = input.next();

            System.out.println ("Please enter a race result (time between 0.00 and 10.00) for runner " + (i+1) );
            resultArray[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  Are you asking what the mathematics is to find the average of a bunch of numbers?  Or how to add numbers together in Java?  Or how to divide numbers in Java?

Comment: I know the maths behind it but I'm struggling with the java syntax even though I have an example to base it on

Comment: Well, the first thing that you're going to need is some kind of variable to store a running total of the times you've entered so far.  You'll need to declare that and set it to zero before your loop begins.  Then, as the user enters each number, you'll want to add it to the running total.  Why don't you give it a try; then when you get stuck, show us the code that you've tried, by appending it to the question; and then we can help you over the next hurdle.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for the help and encouragement! I think that my variable called num stores the number of participants (its the user input at the start of program).  For clarity this is based on just one race

Comment: Sure, but as well as `num` you'll need a variable for the total time.  Maybe a variable of type `float` or type `double` would be appropriate.  And then as the user types times, you'll add them to your variable.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a homework problem so here is how you can solve your problems, **in pseudo-code**:

Total average race time for participants is calculated by summing up all the results and dividing by the amount of results:

```
sum = 0
for i = 0 to results.length      // sum up all the results in a loop
    sum = sum + results[i]          
average = sum / results.length   // divide the sum by the amount of results to get the average
```

It would be even better to perform the summation **while you read user input and store the runner's names and results**. The reason is that it would be more efficient (there would be no need for a second loop to perform the sum) and the code would be cleaner (there would be less of it).

Displaying runners with theirs times can be done by iterating over the two arrays that hold names and results and print values at corresponding index:

```
for i = 0 to results.length
    print "Runner: " + names[i] + " Time: " + results[i]
```

This works because you have the same amount of results and names (`results.length == names.length`), otherwise you would end up with an [**`ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) exception.

---

Another way to do this is to use the object-oriented nature of Java and create an object called `Runner`:

```
class Runner {
    String name;
    double result;
    Runner(String n, double r) {
        result = r;
        name = n;
    }
}
```

Then use an array to store these runners:

```
Runner[] runners = new Runner[num];
for (int i = 0 ; i < num ; i++) {
    System.out.println ("Please enter a race participant Name for runner " + (i+1) );
    String name = input.next();
    System.out.println ("Please enter a race result (time between 0.00 and 10.00) for runner " + (i+1) );
    double result = input.nextDouble();
    runners[i] = new Runner(name, result);
}
```

Then you can just iterate over the array of runners and print the names and the results... Here is pseudo-code for this:

```
for i = 0 to runners.length
    print runners[i].name + " " + runners[i].result
```

Comment: I gave you answers to your two questions but you already have that information? Then why are you asking a question here? :) It is pretty trivial to translate this pseudo-code to `Java` syntax

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need further assistance